# How to map an array with user defined variable array in python to perform some operation?

Tags: python, numpy, mapping

I have an array of dimension 3x3, I would like to first map this array on user define variable of same dimension. Following, I provided an example, where I want to create direct correspondence between `a` and `b`. So for each row I can perform some operation:

```
a=[[11, 2, 7], [5, 7, 8], [4,2,1]]
b= [[pm20, pm30, pm21],[pm21, pm30, pm20],[pm21, pm20, pm30]]
```

For each row, I want to perform following operations:

```
x= pm20-pm21
y= pm30-pm21
```

(I am new to python)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain the operations further?

Comment: Operations are simply subtraction, For first row: `x= pm20-pm21=11-7=4`  similarly    `y= pm30-pm21=2-7=-5`  similarly for other rows.

Comment: You don’t do `pm20 - pm30` ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by _map this array on user define variable of same dimension_ ?

Comment: Actually in  `a=[[11, 2, 7], [5, 7, 8], [4,2,1]]`, indices of each entry have specific name that is `pm20`, `pm30` etc. these are user defined variable (or indices ). The reason for mapping is that these indices are changing the ordering in each row of   `a`. So, if I am in row 1 and I need  `pm20 - pm21` it picks the corresponding value and subtract.

Comment: _The reason for mapping is that these indices are changing the ordering in each row of  a._ Hmm, there might be a simpler way to do this, then. Can you provide some more context?